# Here is the problem discription: print(snake_array[0].x) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x' . I cannot find the mistake

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x, y, dir):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dir = dir


def snake_init(snake_array):
    snake_array.append([Test(300, 300, "RIGHT")])
    snake_array.append([Test(301, 300, "RIGHT")])
    snake_array.append([Test(302, 300, "RIGHT")])
    print(snake_array[0].x)


snake_array = []
snake_init(snake_array)
```

Comment: An error message is not a problem description. Please provide more details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: There's not enough information to determine the problem with your code. Please provide the code for the class test and please make sure the code-block contains all code. Right now it looks like def snake_init(snake_array): and snake_array = [] snake_init(snake_array) are not part of the code.

Comment: @MichaelM. I cant gain x, y and dir attributes from the object. It says there are no such attributes.

Comment: @HubertPastusiak Ah, I see. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending lists to `snake_array`, not `Test` objects. This is what you're appending: `[Test(300, 300, "RIGHT")]`. Notice that the brackets make it a list. All you need to do is remove the extra brackets. Like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x, y, dir):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dir = dir


def snake_init(snake_array):
    snake_array.append(Test(300, 300, "RIGHT"))
    snake_array.append(Test(301, 300, "RIGHT"))
    snake_array.append(Test(302, 300, "RIGHT"))
    print(snake_array[0].x)


snake_array = []
snake_init(snake_array)
```